# I keep having the same problem while updating the reposity on GitHub, whatever I type in git push I get an error

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am a Windows user and I just started on GitHub and I added data to this GitHub repository but I can't update it. I think I just had an error in pushing while updating. I have 1 branch, main. I don't understand why the problem still occurs

```
C:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads\\Projelerim\\Projelerim\\myWork\>git push -u origin main

To github.com:cengizVenes/myWork.git

 ! \[rejected\]        main -\> main (non-fast-forward)

error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:cengizVenes/myWork.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

hint: its remote counterpart. If you want to integrate the remote changes,

hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Did you try doing what it says, or reading any of the (probably thousands) of existing posts about this exact message?

Comment: Err that duplicate I found was not a good reference here. Please read the text you've put in the question: >>> "hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again." <<<

Comment: Is there something you're confused about? I am assuming you have tried using `git pull` before pushing again, since you included that part in the question. If you are not able to pull, then can you share the error message on `git pull`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see this on your error:

`hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

this means your current branch on github has changed(by someone else or possibly by yourself) and now it is different from your current branch in your system.

in order to fix this, you have to pull before you push. as you can see the hint:

`hint: use 'git pull' before pushing again.`

So, in this case i usually use `fetch` command instead of `pull`.(in order to more controle on codes.)
run these command on your terminal:

```
git fetch origin master:test
git rebase test
git push origin HEAD:master
git branch -D test
```

and i hope it will be solved.